# use divs from array as jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript class like this (i know it's technically not a class).

```
function StackMedia (container) {

    this.container = container;
    this.items = container.find('.stackItem');
    console.log("this.items.length: "+this.items.length);

}
```

I pass a container (div) that holds other divs with the css class stackItem, those get stored in items.

Here i want to reuse it:

```
StackMedia.prototype.updatePositions = function() {

     for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
         this.items[i].css('left', 50);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it isn't a jquery object anymore so i get this error:

**TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.items[i].css('left', 50)')**

How can i store them as a jquery object?

---

update

Here is where i create the classes (works fine):

```
// create a stack by passing a container
    $('.stackContainer').each(function(containerIndex) {
        $(this).css('z-index', containerIndex);
        stacks.push(new StackMedia($(this)));
    });
```

This is almost fine apart from the last line

```
StackMedia.prototype.updatePositions = function() {

    var sm = this; // StackMedia

    // set the css properties of the items
    this.items.each(function(i){
        $(this).css('left', sm.x + i * sm.overlapX);
        $(this).css('top', sm.y + i * sm.overlapY);
        $(this).css('width', sm.itemWidth);
        $(this).css('height', sm.itemHeight);
        $(this).find('img').css('width', sm.itemWidth);
        $(this).find('img').css('height', sm.itemHeight);
    });

    // set the css properties of the container
    //console.log(sm);
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).container.css('width', 400);

};
```

I get this again: **TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$(this).container.css')**

So `$(this).container` lost it's jquery functionality, how can i get it back?

Comment: In your update: `$(this).container` should be `this.container`.  Just like you do `this.items`.  `this` is not a jQuery object, it's a `StackMedia` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.items` is a jQuery object.  Don't loop over it using a normal `for` loop, use jQuery's `.each`.

```
this.items.each(function(){
    $(this).css('left', 50);
});
```

I'm pretty sure `.css` affects all elements in a jQuery object, so you can just do:

```
this.items.css('left', 50);
```

Comment: i updated the question, it's quite related i think, would be nice if you can take a second look.

Answer (score 0):

Your divs have css class **stackItem**, so you can easily access those div's using

```
$('.stackItem')
```

It'll return you all DIVs having this class. Try it.

Does not matter what container array contains now. :):)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add an item variable?

```
StackMedia.prototype.updatePositions = function() {
     var item;

     for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
         item = this.items[i];
         $(item).css('left', 50);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably rewrite it as

```
StackMedia.prototype.updatePositions = function() {
   this.items.css('left', 50);
}
```